# Airplay with AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, avplayer, airplay

Is there any way to support [AirPlay](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/features/airplay.html) with `AVPlayer`? I know it can be done with `MPMoviePlayerController`, but I see no indication of AVPlayer support in the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: but what about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021175/airplay-meta-data-on-apple-tv-from-app-avplayer-mpvolumeview

smb did it.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am trying to use AVPlayer to play using AirPlay (without) mirroring and so far no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible in iOS4, but will be in iOS5.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the info -- do you have a source for that?

Comment: Yes, the Apple Developer Documentation on iOS5 shows how to enable Airplay on AVPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

See:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And specifically, set allowsAirPlayVideo to YES

Comment: If someone should stumble across this like I did, note that allowsAirPlayVideo has been deprecated in IOS 6 and replaced with allowsExternalPlayback.

Comment: allowsExternalPlayback does not showing AirPlay option. Any suggestion for me ?